# get tag of element selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get the tag of the element using selenium python?
For eg:

```
    <div class = "...."></div>
```

Is there a way to get the result as **div** if the element is known?
I do know that there's a solution with **bs4** but my routine is well developed in selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebElement` has the `tag_name` property

```
element.tag_name
```

Comment: this is insane! I literally have been searching and none of the answers addressed it straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan you might find [this useful](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html#webdriver-remote), it's Python Selenium API. Focus on `Webdriver.remote` section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium `find_element_by_`

```
Driver = webdriver.Chrome()
element = Driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
element.tag_name
```

The documentation is over [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.__init__).